# How to get related object of existing relation

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have two modules, `Blog` and `Authors`. For each Blog post I want to select author from `Authors` module and show his name and picture:

`blog/index.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
    name: 'blog',
    label: 'Article',
    pluralLabel: 'Articles',
    contextual: true,
    sort: { date: -1 },
    arrangeFields: [
        {
            name: 'content',
            label: 'Content',
            fields: [ 'title', 'shortTitle', 'slug', 'published', 'tags', 'date', 'perex', 'shortPerex', '_author', '_thumbnail' ]
        }
    ],
    addColumns: [
        {
            name: 'date',
            label: 'Date',
            sort: {
                date: -1
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'slug',
            label: 'Slug',
            sort: {
                slug: 1
            }
        }
    ],
    addFields: [
        {
            name: 'title',
            label: 'Title',
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },
        {
            name: 'shortTitle',
            label: 'Short title',
            type: 'string',
            required: false
        },
        {
            name: 'shortPerex',
            label: 'Short perex',
            type: 'string',
            textarea: true,
            required: false
        },
        {
            name: 'perex',
            label: 'Long perex',
            type: 'string',
            textarea: true,
            required: false
        },
        {
            name: 'date',
            label: 'Date',
            type: 'date',
            pikadayOptions: {
                firstDay: 1
            },
            required: true,
            sortify: true
        },
        {
            name: '_author',
            type: 'joinByOne',
            withType: 'author',
            label: 'Author',
            idField: 'authorId',
        },
        {
            name: '_thumbnail',
            type: 'joinByOne',
            withType: 'apostrophe-image',
            label: 'Thumbnail',
            required: true,
        }
    ]
};
```

`authors/index.js`

```
module.exports = {
    extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
    name: 'author',
    label: 'Author',
    pluralLabel: 'Authors',
    searchable: false,
    arrangeFields: [
        {
            name: 'basics',
            label: 'Basics',
            fields: [ 'title', 'nameCZ', 'nameEN', '_thumbnail', 'slug', 'published', 'tags' ]
        }
    ],
    addFields: [
        {
            name: 'name',
            type: 'string',
            label: 'Name',
            required: true
        },
        {
            name: '_thumbnail',
            type: 'joinByOne',
            idField: 'thumbnailId',
            withType: 'apostrophe-image',
            label: 'Picture',
            required: true,
        }
    ]
}
```

`blog-pages/index.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    extend: 'apostrophe-pieces-pages',
    perPage: 99,
    sort: { date: -1 },
}
```

`blog-pages/views/show.html`:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block title %}{{ data.piece.title }} | Costlocker{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    {% set item = data.piece %}
    <h5>Author:</h5>
    <pre>{{ item._author | json}}</pre>
    <hr>
    <h5>Thumbnail:</h5>
    <pre>{{ item._author._thumbnail | json}}</pre>
{% endblock %}
```

Result:

```
<h5>Author:</h5>
{
    "_id": "ckiolmxue003kenrrqjdj20vz",
    "published": true,
    "trash": false,
    "siteMapPriority": null,
    "type": "author",
    "title": "David Maralík",
    "name": "David Maralik",
    "thumbnailId": "ckiolmjqb0033enrr4ol0wl0u",
    "slug": "david-maralík",
    "tags": [

    ],
    "openGraphTitle": "",
    "openGraphDescription": "",
    "openGraphType": "",
    "openGraphImage": {
        "items": [

        ],
        "type": "area",
        "_edit": true,
        "_docId": "ckiolnuto0058enrr99bl4d4j",
        "_dotPath": "_author.openGraphImage"
    },
    "workflowLocale": "en-draft",
    "workflowGuid": "ckiolmxue003jenrric96iw8g",
    "createdAt": "2020-12-14T13:34:54.422Z",
    "titleSortified": "david maralík",
    "updatedAt": "2020-12-14T13:34:54.424Z",
    "highSearchText": "david maralík david maralík david maralík david maralík david maralik david maralík",
    "highSearchWords": [
        "david",
        "maralík",
        "maralik"
    ],
    "lowSearchText": "david maralík david maralík david maralík david maralík david maralik david maralík",
    "searchSummary": "",
    "viewGroupsIds": [

    ],
    "viewUsersIds": [

    ],
    "editGroupsIds": [

    ],
    "editUsersIds": [

    ],
    "docPermissions": [

    ],
    "editGroupsRelationships": {
    },
    "editUsersRelationships": {
    },
    "loginRequired": null,
    "viewGroupsRelationships": {
    },
    "viewUsersRelationships": {
    },
    "workflowLastEditor": "admin",
    "workflowLastEditorId": "ckioleo9j00068qrr59o3k4r4",
    "workflowModified": false,
    "workflowLastCommitted": {
        "at": "2020-12-14T13:41:52.420Z",
        "user": {
            "username": "admin",
            "title": "admin",
            "_id": "ckioleo9j00068qrr59o3k4r4"
        }
    },
    "_edit": true,
    "_publish": true,
    "_originalWidgets": {
    }
}
<h5>Thumbnail:</h5>
null
```

How to get `_thumbnail.attachment` of the `Author`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of observations:

1. Define the thumbnail field like this:

> ```
> {
>       name: 'image',
>       label: 'Image',
>       type: 'singleton',
>       widgetType: 'apostrophe-images',
>       options: {
>         limit: 1,
>         focalPoint: true
>       }
>     }
> ```

The way you're adding it now looks more like you're adding an instance from another piece type and not a field of THIS author.

2. When you add the author to the blog piece do it like this:

> ```
> {
>   name: '_author',
>   label: 'Author',
>   type: 'joinByOne',
>   withType: 'author',
>   required: true,
>   filters: {
>     projection: {
>       title: 1,
>       thumbnail: 1
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

The projection helps you get only the fields that you need and not everything else.

I believe this should help you get the thumbnail like this:

```
{{ item._author.thumbnail | json}}
```